# Replacement for ASM's Classic Window Mode in Mavericks?

Tags: mac, macos, ui, menu-bar

Once upon a time there was a Menu Extra called ASM ( Application Switcher Menu) which automatically brought all of an application's windows to the front when any of its windows was clicked. In the Finder, clicking anywhere on the desktop brought all Finder windows to the front.

Is there a replacement app for this behavior on 10.8 or 10.9, or a preference setting? Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 1):

[Xassist](https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/5760/x-assist) seems to be the best option.